# Email multiple cells to recipient instead of one email per cell using Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Currently I'm working on a script that checks values of one column and based on that send email containing information from another column. Everything works perfectly except one thing - it send one email per value and I'd like to send all the values in one email. Can someone please help with the issue ?

````
const helpsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('Sheet');
 const date =  helpsheet.getRange(1,10).getValue();


 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID2");
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
 const data = sh.getRange('A2:c'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();

var recipients = 'EMAIL@EMAIL';
var subject = 'SUBJECT'; 
 
 data.forEach(r=>{
    let overdueValue = r[2];  
    if (overdueValue > date)
    
    
    {
        let path = r[0];


 MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: recipients,
   subject: subject,
   htmlBody: 'Hi guys ' + path +'!<br><br>Best regards,'
 });

    }
 });  
} ```
````

Comment: Don't you mean one value per email?  `data.forEach( r =>` will only generate up to number of rows emails if all dates pass the if test.  Try `let path = JSON.stringify(r);`

Comment: I've tried but it still sends 5 emails with different data instead of one email containing all of them

Comment: Can you post the complete code because I'm not seeing it.  You only have one loop `data.forEach()` which passes a row of data to its function.  If it passes the test then it would send an email and then go to the next row.  There is nothing that loops through each column of a row.  Unless its your date comparison that is always true so its send one for each row, is that it?  Can you `console.log(overdueValue)` and `console.log(date)` and see what they are?

Comment: Or is it that you want only one email containing all the rows that pass the test?

Comment: This is the whole code. Exactly! I want only one email containing all the rows/cell that pass the test. I tried to put for loop in it but then I was receiving hundreds of emails, I'm pretty sure there was some mistake and it looped a bit crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I can't test this because 1st I don't want a bunch of emails to myself and 2nd I don't have a data set that matches your data, but I'm pretty sure this will do what you want.  What I do is build an array of rows that pass the sniff test using the Array push method below.  Then when I have all the rows that pass I send one email.

I have edited this post to include functions to create an html table.

```
function test() {
  try {
    const helpsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName('Sheet');
    const date =  helpsheet.getRange(1,10).getValue();

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID2");
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
    const data = sh.getRange('A2:c'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();

    var pre = "Hello";
    var post = "Best regards";
    var recipients = 'EMAIL@EMAIL';
    var subject = 'SUBJECT'; 
    var passed = [];
    data.forEach( r => {
      let overdueValue = r[2];  
      if (overdueValue > date) {
        passed.push(r);
      }
    });

    if( passed.length > 0 ) {  // maybe nothing passed the test
      var html = createHTMLfile(true);
      html = html.concat("<p>"+pre+"</p>");
      html = html.concat(createTable(passed));
      html = html.concat(createHTMLfile());
      html = html.concat("<p>"+post+"</p>");
      MailApp.sendEmail( {
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: html });
      };
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I have added the additional functions to create the table.  You are welcome to play with the `<style>`s.

```
function createHTMLfile(pre) {
  if( pre ) {
    return "<html><head><style>table, td { border: thin solid black; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center }</style></head><body>";
  }
  else {
    return "</body></html>";
  }
}

function createTable(data) {
  try {
    var width = 600/data[0].length;
    var table = "<table>";
    function addCell(value) {
      table = table.concat("<td style=width:"+width+"px>");
      table = table.concat(value.toString());
      table = table.concat("</td>");
    }
    function addRow(row) {
      table = table.concat("<tr>");
      row.forEach( addCell );
      table = table.concat("</tr>");
    }
    data.forEach( addRow )
    table = table.concat("</table>");
    return table;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! thanks a lot, it's exactly what i was searching for

Comment: I leave it up to you to pretty up the htmlBody but I do have a routine that would create an html table if you like.

Comment: that would be even more amazing, if you don't mind sharing of course